# Directory.Exists (Dir) function not working as expected

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

In my code I need to check if a directory exists, and if it ddoesn't, create it.

Unfortunately even though the `Directory.Exists` returns false, the directory exists and an execption is thrown.

here is the code I am using:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(emailAttachmentsPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(emailAttachmentsPath);
}
```

even though that directory exists on disk, the function returns false and I get an error.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You can safely use `Directory.CreateDirectory` without checking for existence. It won't overwrite anything. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx): _" If the directory already exists, this method does not create a new directory, but it returns a DirectoryInfo object for the existing directory"_

Comment: Which type of exception is thrown?

Comment: At a guess, a *file* with that name exists. That'll cause an exception to be thrown. But, of course, `Directory.Exists()` will return false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A guess, make sure `emailAttachmentsPath` do not contain filename. See the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) here:

> Return Value Type: 
>   System.Boolean
>   true if path refers to an existing
>   directory; false **if the directory does not exist** or **an error occurs**
>   *when trying to determine if the specified **file** exists*. 
>   true if path
>   refers to an existing directory; otherwise, false.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> If you do not have at a minimum read-only permission to the directory,
>   the Exists method will return false.
>
> The Exists method returns false if any error occurs while trying to
>   determine if the specified file exists. This can occur in situations
>   that raise exceptions such as passing a file name with invalid
>   characters or too many characters, a failing or missing disk, or if
>   the caller does not have permission to read the file.